# GitLab authentication failure with Github account

Tags: gitlab

I recently created a project on gitlab logged with my Github account.

But when cloning the project with gitbash (with my current ssh-key added to the gitlab account) the shell prompts for username/password, entering my username and password from github results in failure on authentication. (also email/password fails)

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the ssh url? The SSH URL has the username included and, thus, git won't ask for it.

Comment: @MrTux your comment should be the Nr. 1 answer. Worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

> Updated as of 4/28/2020 4:00 PM (Philippine Standard Time) to include scopes for private repos.

You need to create an access token from your GitLab account if you not yet set up a password or if protected by 2FA.

- Login to your GL instance account, as usual.
- Click your profile picture and select **Settings**.
- On **User Settings** sidebar, click **Access tokens**.
- At the **Add a personal access token** section, give a unique name and, optionally expiration date.
- Select `api` only as scope for your new access token. If you're working in private projects, also include `read_repository` and `write_repository` scopes.
  [image: Creating a new access token in GitLab.com]
- Hit **Create personal access token** and let GitLab generate it for you.
- Copy the access token. You'll be not able to see it again for security reasons. [Instance Admins can help you create API keys, but they'll also see this once](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html#create-an-impersonation-token).
  [image]

> **Treat your access tokens like your passwords!** Keep your scopes for next access tokens low and only share it with person/people you trust. Because I shared the example token here, any attempts to use it were now triggering errors because I revoked it before I update my answers.

Then, try logging in when using `git push`.

```sh
## Init the local repo
mkdir test-to-connect
cd test-to-connect
git init

## Add your user name and email to Git.
git config --global user.name "Your name"
git config --global user.email "your-gl-account-email@example.com"


## Create a new private repo after pushing.
git remote set origin https://your-gl-instance-host.dev/your-username/your-new-project-slug

## Commit
git commit -m "Initial commit"

## Push to GitLab
git push origin
## Username for 'https://your-gl-instance-host.dev': your-username
## Password for 'https://your-username@your-gl-instance-host.dev' [REDACTED]
```